Cannot implement radiobutton deselect in HTML (.JSP) file
I want to save working hours in two option, first <form:input> or second radiobutton "24/7". While choose "24/7" radiobutton cannot deselect button.
Here is my form in .jsp file:
What I tried:
I tried everything but radiobutton dont want to deselect)
My expectation is:
When click to 24/7 radiobutton it should deselect


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  const radio = document.getElementById('workingHours247');
  const textInput = document.getElementById('deviceWorkingHours');

  toggleWorkingHoursInput(radio);

  radio.addEventListener('change', function() {
    toggleWorkingHoursInput(this);
  });

  textInput.addEventListener('focus', function() {
    const radio = document.getElementById('workingHours247');
    radio.checked = false;
    toggleWorkingHoursInput(radio);
  });
});

function toggleWorkingHoursInput(radio) {
  const textInput = document.getElementById('deviceWorkingHours');

  if (radio.checked) {
    textInput.disabled = true;
    textInput.value = '24/7';
  } else {
    textInput.disabled = false;
    textInput.value = '';
  }
}
<div class="margin-vertical-10 col-xs-12">
  <div class="form-centered">
    <div class="label-float overme-ovr">
      <label for="deviceWorkingHours" class="overme llabel">Рабочие часы</label>
    </div>
    <form:input disabled="${disable}" path="deviceWorkingHours" id="deviceWorkingHours" type="text" placeholder="08:00 - 23:00" class="form-control" style="width: 25%" />
    <div class="radio-custom radio-primary">
      <form:radiobutton disabled="${disable}" id="workingHours247" path="deviceWorkingHours" name="workingHours247" value="24/7" />
      <label for="deviceWorkingHours" class="cursor-default">24/7</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-centered">
      <form:errors path="deviceWorkingHours" style="color:red;" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Are there any errors in your console? Why not use a checkbox instead?

If your radio button is checked, you have disabled your text input. Radios can't be unchecked by the user, so your text input won't be re-enabled. However, checkboxes can be unchecked by the user.

Please update the snippet I made with rendered HTML

There's no any radio button in the updated code snippet.

In future client side related questions you better post the generated HTML code instead of the raw server side source code. Open webpage in webbrowser and do right click and View Page Source and then copy the relevant HTML from there -- in properly formatted [mcve] fashion of course. JavaScript does namely not run on server side but on client side.

@mykaf Thanks for your advice, I used the checkbox instead of the radio button
